# Third degree Taylor polynomial of $\frac{1}{x^2+2x+2}$ at $x=0$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I first thought to use the Taylor series of $\displaystyle \frac{1}{1+x}$, which makes
$$\frac{1}{x^2+2x+2}=\frac{1}{1+(x+1)^2}=1-(x+1)^2+(x+1)^4-\cdots$$
However, because the series goes like $(1-1+1-\cdots)+(-2x+4x-6x+\cdots)+\cdots$, I have no idea how to get a third degree Taylor polynominal with this approach.

Could I get some hints to get the polynominal, except the solution below?

This is the only solution I got:

Let $g(x)=x^2+2x+2$. Then,

$\displaystyle f(x)=\frac{1}{g(x)}$

$\displaystyle f'(x)=-\frac{g'(x)}{g(x)^2}$

$\displaystyle f''(x)=-\frac{g''(x)g(x)^2-2g(x)g'(x)^2}{g(x)^4}=-\frac{g''(x)}{g(x)^2}+\frac{2g'(x)^2}{g(x)^3}$

$f\displaystyle^{(3)}(x)=-\frac{g^{(3)}g(x)^2-2g'(x)g(x)g''(x)}{g(x)^4}+2\left(\frac{2g''(x)g'(x)g^3(x)-3g^2(x)g'(x)^3}{g(x)^6}\right)$

And,

$g(x)=x^2+2x+2 \quad \rightarrow \quad g(0)=2\quad \Rightarrow \quad f(0)=\frac{1}{2}$

$g'(x)=2x+2 \quad \rightarrow \quad g'(0)=2\quad \Rightarrow \quad f'(0)=-\frac{1}{2}$

$g''(x)=2 \quad \rightarrow \quad g''(0)=2\quad \Rightarrow \quad f''(0)=\frac{1}{2}$

$g^{(3)}(x)=0 \quad \rightarrow \quad g^{(3)}(0)=0\quad \Rightarrow \quad f^{(3)}(0)=0$

Therefore,

$\displaystyle T_3f(x)=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}x+\frac{1}{4}x^2$.

Comment: Use the long division

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right to think about $\frac{1}{1+x}$, however, your approach of factorizing to get $\frac{1}{1+(x+1)^2}$ will not work because you want the Taylor expansion about the origin, meaning you want small $|x|$. However, if $|x|$ is small, then $|x+1|$ is not small (recall that the geometric series is only convergent when the term has absolute value less than $1$). More concretely, if you have $|x|<\delta<1$, then $|x+1|\geq 1-|x|\geq 1-\delta$. This is a quantitative description of how small $|x+1|$ can be (not very small since it is lower bounded by the positive number $1-\delta$). If the question had asked for the expansion about $-1$, then what you did would be perfect.

To fix the issue, it's just a small algebraic trick. We have
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{x^2+2x+2}&=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{1+\left(x+\frac{x^2}{2}\right)}
\end{align}
Now, note that if $x$ is small, then so is $x+\frac{x^2}{2}$ (essentially, I'm saying that by continuity of $x\mapsto x+\frac{x^2}{2}$, the limit as $x\to 0$ of this function is $0$). So, if you now call $\xi=x+\frac{x^2}{2}$, then you can expand $\frac{1}{1+\xi}=1-\xi+\xi^2-\xi^3+O(\xi^4)=1-\xi+\xi^2-\xi^3+O(x^4)$. So just plug in $\xi=x+\frac{x^2}{2}$, expand the quadratic, and keep only up to $x^3$. Of course, if you want a higher Taylor polynomial, you just keep more terms.

Comment: The idea is sound, but the problem is asking for the third order Taylor polynomial, so we need to take one more term and then keep everything up to $x^3$.

Comment: @Aaron right, perhaps you were commenting about my answer prior to my edit. Initially, I had seen that OP's final answer was $=\cdots +\frac{1}{4}x^2$ in the last line of their post, so I naively assumed they were simply looking for the second order Taylor polynomial, but then I read the question more carefully, and edited accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the Taylor polynomial is
$$\frac{1}{x^2+2x+2} = a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + a_3 x^3 + \cdots.$$
Then multiplying both sides by $x^2+2x+2$, we get
$$1 = 2a_0 + (2a_0+2a_1) x + (a_0+2a_1+2a_2) x^2 + (a_1+2a_2+2a_3) x^3 + \cdots.$$
Therefore, equating coefficients on both sides gives
\begin{align*}
1 & = 2 a_0 \\
0 & = 2a_0 + 2a_1 \\
0 &= a_0+2a_1+2a_2 \\
0 &= a_1+2a_2+2a_3 \\
  & \vdots
\end{align*}
Solving these equations from top to bottom then gives $a_0 = \frac{1}{2}$, $a_1 = -\frac{1}{2}$, $a_2 = \frac{1}{4}$, $a_3 = 0$, $\ldots$.